# неправильно отображается в HTML текст из mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

пытаюсь вывести на страницу в отдельные блоки данные из таблицы, но если текст немного длиннее то все идёт в одну строку  как будто игнорит CSS.

вот так должно выглядеть 
[image: 1_1]
так выглядит когда создаётся блок через пхп
[image: 2_2]

```
//html код блока
<div id="article"> 
          <img src="img/1.jpg">
          <h2><a href="/full_article.php">Ce este Lorem Ipsum?Ce este Lorem Ipsum?Ce este Lorem Ipsum?</a></h2>
          <P>
          Lorem Ipsum este pur şi simplu o machetă pentru text a industriei      tipografice. </p>
      </div>
//html код блока

<?php
include 'db.php';

$sql = "SELECT title, text, autor, date, img_url FROM blogbase  ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div id="article">';
    echo '<img src="'.$row['img_url'].'">';
    echo '<h2><a href="/full_article.php">'.$row['title'].'</a></h2>';
    echo '<p>'.$row['text'].'</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    //echo '<div id="article">'.'<img src="'.$row['img_url'].'">'.'<h2><a href="/full_article.php">'.$row['title'].'</a></h2>'.'<p>'.$row['text'].'</p>'.'</div>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: в данном случае вам нужно показать не код пхп, а выложить результирующий html и ваш  css к этому коду.... когда вы поймете почему так отображает браузер, только тогда можно будет что-то править....

Comment: Скорее всего выходит так - <p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p></p>

Comment: вы в вашем `LONGLONGLONGTEXT` попробуйте пробелов поставить для начала.

Comment: либо задавайте `owerflow-wrap: break-word;` и `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключевое различие между вашим примером "как должно быть" и как получается заключается в длине строк. Как видно, во втором случае у вас используются очень длинные строки без пробелов. В такой ситуации обычным поведением является перенос строки в более широкую часть блока, а если строка все равно не влезает, то она "заходит" за края контейнера.

В связи с этим, если свои тестовые данные вы приблизите к более "реальному" варианту, добавив пробелы, то проблема исчезнет сама собой.

Также для принудительной разбивки длинной строки и ее переноса следует использовать `css`-стили `overflow-wrap: break-word;` (CSS3) и более старую версию `word-wrap: break-word`.
В `CSS3` также добавлено свойство `hyphens`, отвечающее за расстановку дефисов при переносе строк, однако, оно поддерживается не всеми браузерами.

*зы: как видно привязка к `mysql` и `php` в вашем вопросе не корректна, измените тэги и заголовок вопроса.

зы2: если выводите несколько таких блоков  на странице, то измените `id="article"` на `class="article"`

зы3: разделяйте логику и представление в коде, используйте шаблоны, не генерируйте html-код посреди пхп-кода.*

```css
.article {
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;   
   margin: 10px
}

.wbreak {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext
</div>

<div class="article wbreak">
longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext
</div>
```